# Proof explanation of $P(p^e) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(p^{e-1})\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory, group-isomorphism

The following is from Classical Theory of Algebraic Numbers by
Paulo Ribenboim :
[image]
$P(p^e)$ is the set of all nonzero 
residue classes a modulo m, where gcd(a, m) = 1.

My question underlined and in order of "reading text":

1- The text concludes $P(p^e)$ to be cyclic based on being 'component-wise' cyclic': Why this is true, i.e. Why if $A=B \times C$ with $B\cap C={\{1}\}$ and $B$ and $C$ are both cyclic so is their product $A$?

2- Why $B\cap C = {\{\overline{1}\}}$?

3- **a.** Why $\overline{a}^{p^{e-1}} \in B$ for every $\overline{a} \in P(p)$? And, **b.** Isn't it supposed to be $\overline{\overline{a}} \in P(p)$ or $\overline{a} \in P(p^e)$, because $\overline{a} \notin P(p)$? if so, still the question "**a.**" without answer.

4- Why $\overline{\overline{a}}^{p^{e-1}} = \overline{\overline{a}}$? (If it was $\overline{\overline{a}}^{p} \equiv \overline{\overline{a}}$ yes true by Fermat's theorem.)

Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let $x$ be a generator of $B$ and let $y$ be a generator of $C$.  Then $o(x, y) = \operatorname{lcm} (o(x), o(y)) = \frac{o(x) \cdot o(y)}{\gcd(o(x), o(y))}=o(x) \cdot o(y).$
2. We know from above that $|C|=p^{e-1}$, with $p$ prime, so every element of $C$ must have some power of $p$ as its order.  On the other hand, every element of $B$ has order dividing $p-1$, so no element of $B$ can have a power of $p$ as its order, other than $1$.
3. If $x \in P(p)$, then $(x^{p^{e-1}})\in P(p)$.  Also, $|P(p)| = p-1$, so $(x^{p^{e-1}})\in P(p) \Rightarrow (x^{p^{e-1}})^{p-1}=1 \Rightarrow (x^{p^{e-1}})\in B$ by the definition of $B$.
4. You can easily see this by induction.  $x^{p^2}=(x^p)^p = x^p=x$, and $x^{p^{n+1}}=(x^{p^n})^p$.  By inductive hypothesis $x^{p^n}=x$, so $x^{p^{n+1}}=x^p=x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is one of the clearest answers I've ever read on MSE! :))

Comment: I'm glad to know that 26 years as a lawyer has taught me a little something about communicating clearly.  Glad I could help.